# Multiplying each sublist by a constant

Tags: python

```
l2=[[13,11,9],[7,5,3],[1]]
```

I want to multiply each sublist in list  `l2` with a constant number i.e 13*1,11*1,9*1 and 7*2,5*2,3*2 and 1*3 and the final result would be 13,11,9 and 14,10,6 and 3.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); **asking us to write the program for you**, suggestions, and external links are **off-topic.**

Comment: This is a more general versionof https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671999/python-multiply-each-item-in-sublists-by-a-list .. if the list would contain the same number instead of different ones... similarly question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446338/how-to-multiply-all-integers-inside-list/26446368 and there are about a dozend more on SO already

Answer (score 1):

Using `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
l2=[[13,11,9],[7,5,3],[1]]
print([[j*i for j in v] for i, v in enumerate(l2, 1)])
```

**Output:**

```
[[13, 11, 9], [14, 10, 6], [3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `enumerate` here:

```
l2 = [[13,11,9],[7,5,3],[1]]

l3 = [[x * (idx + 1) for x in sublist] for idx, sublist in enumerate(l2)]
print(l3)
```

This yields

```
[[13, 11, 9], [14, 10, 6], [3]]
```

Comment: Type Errror:'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Your error makes no sense. At least not with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l2=[[13,11,9],[7,5,3],[1]]

counter = 1
for i in range(len(l2)):
    for j in range(len(l2[i])):
        l2[i][j] *= counter        
    counter += 1

print(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it always the first sublist is 1, the 2nd is two, etc?

```
for i in range(0, len(l2)):
    i += 1
    print(f'{l2[i-1]} times {i}')
    print(list(map(lambda x: x*i, l2[i-1])))
```

Comment: Yes the first sublist is always 1

Comment: why not `range(1,len(l2)+1)` to remove an extra step

Comment: I thought about that, too. Figured it was about 50/50 on which was better.

Answer (score 0):

One liner with `map` and `enumerate`

```
[map((idx).__mul__, sublist) for idx,sublist in enumerate(l2,1)] #[[13, 11, 9], [14, 10, 6], [3]]
```

using `numpy.multiply`

```
import numpy as np
[np.multiply(sublist,[idx]).tolist() for idx,sublist in enumerate(l2,1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = []
multiplier = 1 
# passing over sublists( e.g. [13,11,9] = li) in l2
for li in l2: 
    # multiply all elements in sublist(li) with multiplier(in first step multiplier = 1)
    # append the multiplied sublist to the new list
    new_list.append([li[i]*multiplier for i in range(len(li))])
    # multiplier increase by one (e.g. in second step we need to multiply elements from second sublist with multiplier = 2)
    multiplier += 1
print (new_list)
```